My PS4 doesn't show recent gaming progress on my PSN profile
My online profile only shows games I played a while ago. I've played way more games and earned a lot more trophies, but it doesn't show those on my profile. And when I check my PS app, it says I've only played Fortnite for 1 hour, for example, but I've been playing since like 2018. It does the same thing for Apex, Genshin Impact, etc.
Does anyone know how to fix this?

Hi Mia, have you maybe set your online profile to private or something like that? I'm not familiar with PS(N), but most gaming platform profiles allow for more private settings like that.

@Joachim I'm also not that familiar but I would think privacy settings would not affect to the account holder, I mean, why would it? Did you ever met that kind of gaming platform?

@Skye-AT Good point, but the OP talks about "my online profile" and that could mean they view it online, where they're not logged in. But you're probably right :)

@Joachim If that is the case then it wouldn't show these games(the games listed by OP) in the first place, I guess.

Have you tried a third party service like PSN profiles? So you can check if it's a problem with your account or the app itself

@pinckerman I haven't but I'll try that out

This is most likely a bug on Sony backend that occured after a system update, as suggested on several posts on Reddit and Gamefaqs.
Nothing you can (sadly) really solve by yourself.
